# Sort HashMap based on multiple conditions

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I have a HashMap with the following structure,

```
    {val1#val2=val3#val4-val5}
```

where key = val1#val2 and value=val3#val4-val5 ,

```
HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    h.put("aaa#bbb", "111#444-555");
    h.put("bbb#aaa", "222#ddd-222");
    h.put("111#999", "000#213-aaa");
```

I have three conditions where I have to sort the map as,
1. By val1.
2. By val2.
3. By val3.

Comment: First off, you probably want to use a `LinkedHashMap`, since normal hash maps don't keep the order.

Comment: Also, will the values always consist of 3 characters?

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? Sorting the map based on their keys?

Comment: No the values will be seperated by # @Schred

Comment: Do you want to sort either by `val1` or by `val2` or by `val3`? Or do you want to sort by some combination of those values? Please [edit] your question and post your expected result, i.e. write the map entries in the order you want them.

Comment: `HashMap` is unordered. You can't sort it at all, let alone 'based on different conditions'. Use a `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 3):

HashMaps don't guarantee order, in order to get sorted map you need to use LinkedHashMap.

To sort the keys you could use the java stream api, sort the map entries and the insert them in LinkedHashMap.

```
    Map<String, String> h = new HashMap<>();
    h.put("aaa#bbb", "111#444-555");
    h.put("bbb#aaa", "222#ddd-222");
    h.put("111#999", "000#213-aaa");

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    h.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey().split("#")[0]))// sort by val1
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getKey().split("#")[1]))// sort by val2
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().split("#")[0]))// sort by val3
        .forEach(e -> {
            linkedHashMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("aa#bb", "11111#44-5555555");
    map.put("bb#aa", "22222#ddd-222");
    map.put("11#99", "00000#213-aaa");

    Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> byVal1 = 
             entry -> entry.getKey().substring(0, entry.getKey().indexOf('#'));
    Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> byVal2 =
             entry -> entry.getKey().substring(entry.getKey().indexOf('#') + 1);
    Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> byVal3 =
             entry -> entry.getValue().substring(0, entry.getValue().indexOf('#'));

    // Just change this value to sort by a different value
    Function<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> value = byVal3;

    List<Map.Entry<String, String>> asList = map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(value)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    map.clear();
    asList.forEach(entry -> map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

    map.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry));
}
```

You of course don't have to create the `byValX` functions in the method and could use method references instead.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if that is what you want to accomplish (clarify what needs to be done and I can adapt the solution), but you can use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class TestDictionary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Key, Object> map = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Key>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Key o1, Key o2) {
            // do whatever you want here
            return 0;
        }
    });

        map.put(new Key("a", "b", "c"), new Value());
        map.put(new Key("b", "c", "a"), new Value());
        map.put(new Key("c", "b", "a"), new Value());
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    static class Key {
        String val1;
        String val2;
        String val3;

        public Key(String val1, String val2, String val3) {
            this.val1 = val1;
            this.val2 = val2;
            this.val3 = val3;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            Key key = (Key) o;
            return val1.equals(key.val1) &&
                   val2.equals(key.val2) &&
                   val3.equals(key.val3);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(val1, val2, val3);
        }
    }

    static class Value {
        int number;
    }
}
```